# Munin graph Disk IOs for /dev/sda k unit interpretation

Tags: munin, io

From Munin diskstats plugin Disk IOs for /dev/sda graph shows Max IO/sec -read/+write 1.75k/920.92.
What does the k unit in Disk IOs graph mean?

Answer (score 2):

k == kilo == 1,000 == 10e3

That means 1,750 reads/second and 920 writes/second were your maximum values.

But that should also be clear from your graph... Looking at my graph below, you can see read maximum values of 1,753 very prominently...

[image]

Comment: can this values be translated in IOPS?

Comment: Yes, the sum of these at any point in time would be your IOPS.